# cleanup all items in a ViewModel when closing window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, resource-cleanup

I have `RichBox` binded to a `List<String>ListName` in the using of the window I add some item in this list, but after I close this window and I open it i still have the old added name, I know that the View model don't be disposed when I close window, but I use this on closing

```
public virtual void Cleanup()
{
    this.MessengerInstance.Unregister(this);
}
```

but this will clean only the `Messenger` and let all my other items with values, I want to clear all resource in this ViewModel when I close the window

*Update :*

with Rudi answer I try on closing to do

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<ScanViewModel>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ScanViewModel>();
```

and it work, but it seems not right to me to Unregister the VM and register it again !

Answer (score 2):

You can just unregister an instance of the class than remove the entire class if you want.

Snippet from `SimpleIoc.cs`:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Removes the instance corresponding to the given key from the cache. The class
//     itself remains registered and can be used to create other instances.
//
// Parameters:
//   key:
//     The key corresponding to the instance that must be removed.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TClass:
//     The type of the instance to be removed.
public void Unregister<TClass>(string key) where TClass : class;
```

Do keep in mind to get a new instance of the class on every resolve from `SimpleIoC` we need to specify a unique key to it in `GetInstance()`

so in `ViewModelLocator.cs` keep a reference to the `currentKey` used and un-register it on the next attempt, something like:

```
private string _currentScanVMKey;
public ScanViewModel Scan
{
  get {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentScanVMKey))
      SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(_currentScanVMKey);
    _currentScanVMKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ScanViewModel>(_currentScanVMKey);
  }
}
```

This way each time the VMLocator is queried for `Scan` a new VM is returned after unregistering the current VM. This approach would comply with the guidelines suggested by "Laurent Bugnion" [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342294/simpleioc-can-it-provide-new-instance-each-time-required) and I'd take it he knows his own libraries pretty well and you're not going to go wrong doing it that way.

I remember MVVM Light's author state somewhere `SimpleIoC` was intended to get dev's familiar with IOC principles and let them explore it for themselves. It's great for simple project's, If you do want more and more control over your VM injections then I'd suggest looking at things like [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203101.aspx) in which your current situation would have been resolved pretty easily since you could just go

```
// _container is a UnityContainer
_container.RegisterType<ScanViewModel>();  // Defaults to new instance each time when resolved
_container.RegisterInstance<ScanViewModel>();  // Defaults to a singleton approach
```

You also get LifeTimeManagers and sorts that give even greater control. Yes Unity is an overhead compared to `SimpleIoC`, but it's what the technology can provide when needed than having to write code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do it:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<ViewModelName>();
```

edit: how about this

```
    public ViewModelName MyViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            ViewModelName vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ViewModelName>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<ViewModelName>();
            //or SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<ViewModelName>(MyViewModel);
            return vm;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but in this case when I open the same window again nothing work(there's not a VM for the View)

Comment: you could re-register the ViewModel `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ViewModelName>();` , but since I don't use this I can't say if it would actually work or if this is the right method to do it like this.

Comment: I test it and it work, but I don't see that a good practice to do it for every VM