# How to reset all instances in IOC Container

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I have made an C# WPF Application using the [MVVM Light framework](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). My Application uses the `ViewModelLocator` class to locate the viewmodels during runtime. The `ViewModelLocator` makes usage of the `SimpleIoc` class which also comes with the [MVVM Light framework](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/).

Here is my scenario: 
The user logs in an can use my application. On logout, i want to dispose/reset/recreate all viewmodel instances to provide a clean environment to the next user.

I tried to implement the `Cleanup()` method in the `ViewModelLocator` class but it is not working.
Not working means that the (second) user sees the data from the user who was logged in before.

first try:

```
public static void Cleanup()
{
   SimpleIoc.Default.Reset();
}
```

second try:

```
public static void Cleanup()
{
   SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<LoginViewModel>();
   SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<TaskViewModel>();

   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TaskViewModel>();
}
```

third try (not what i want but it is a workaround):

```
public static void Cleanup()
{
   // I implemented the ICleanup interface in my viewmodels
   // The cleanup method clears all my variables eg: myCollection.clear();
   SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>().Cleanup();
   SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<TaskViewModel>().Cleanup();
}
```

How do i reset all instances in my `ViewModelLocator` class? I'm willing to use a more advanced Ioc Container if necessary.

Comment: What's wrong with the third approach? Can the objects not be reused?

Comment: I have some logic in my constructors which prepare some things for the current user. This won't work any longer. I also have to write a lot of code which needs to be maintained (cleanup method for every viewmodel).  The approach to throw away the old instances seems far more straightforward to me.

Comment: According to the MVVM Light maintainer this is the recommended approach. [SimpleIoc - can it provide new instance each time required?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9350917/580951). If that doesn't fit your architecture then it might be better to switch to another IOC.

Comment: Do you know other IOCs?

Comment: I've used [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) and [AutoFac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/). IOCs aren't hard to write and there's a pretty good comparison at [IOC Battle](http://www.iocbattle.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `SimpleIoC`

I'd add a public static property with a private string backend for a unique `Key`

something like

```
private static string _currentKey = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
public static string CurrentKey {
  get {
    return _currentKey;
  }
  private set {
    _currentKey = value;
  }
}
```

and have the cleanup method to unregister VM's with current key and finally reset the current key(invoke on each app reset stage):

```
public static void Cleanup() {
  SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<LoginViewModel>(CurrentKey);
  ...
  CurrentKey = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

and when calling `GetInstance(...)` just pass in the static `CurrentKey`.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>(ViewModelLocator.CurrentKey);
```

Comment: worked for me but i still prefer to change the IOC Container. Nevertheless this is a working solution and therefore the correct answer.

Comment: @Joel well if you choose to change the IoC container to a more elaborate one, you can take Unity where you can give your instances an `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` which will just let the GC garbage collect the instance of the VM once nothing is having a strong reference to it after your logout. You have couple more Managers as well to manage Life-time of your objects. however there is absolutely nothing "wrong" in `SimpleIoC` regarding this

Comment: yeah i use Unity now. This was not about right or wrong it was just that `SimpeIoC` doesn't fit all of my needs.